# In redux, how should I update information located outside of the sub-object visible to a sub-reducer?

Tags: javascript, redux

An application retrieves slides over HTTP and then displays them.

The shape of the state for this application is:

```js
{
    errorMessage: '',
    slides: {
        isFetching: false,
        currentIndex: 0, 
        slides: []
    }
}
```

I create a sub-reducer (is this the correct term?) for the top-level slides property:

```
const initialState = {
    isFetching: false,
    currentIndex: 0, 
    slides: []
}

export function slidesReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_SLIDES_REQUEST:
            return ({ ...state, isFetching: true })
        case FETCH_SLIDES_SUCCESS:
            return ({ ...state, isFetching: false, slides: action.slides })
        case FETCH_SLIDES_ERROR:
            return ({ ...state, isFetching: false }) // I want to update the error message
    }
}
```

I want to update the `errorMessage` property on the root of the store when `FETCH_SLIDES_ERROR` occurs, but the `errorMessage` property on the root of the store is not within the store sub-object visible by this sub-reducer.

How should I do this?

Do I simply listen for `FETCH_SLIDES_ERROR` on the reducer covering the root of the store?

Answer (score 0):

in redux, we create root reducer which we combine all reducers with method called combineReducer so my suggestion to you is making two files one for root reducer and the second for the fetch slides reducer call it slidesReducer or any name you would like.
in the slidesReducer put the error message on it like this:

```
 const initialState = {
    isFetching: false,
    currentIndex: 0,
    errorMessage: "",
    slides: []
}

export function slidesReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_SLIDES_REQUEST:
            return ({ ...state, isFetching: true })
        case FETCH_SLIDES_SUCCESS:
            return ({ ...state, isFetching: false, slides: action.slides })
        case FETCH_SLIDES_ERROR:
            return ({ ...state, isFetching: false, errorMessgae: action.errorMessage })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The example in my question is contrived specifically for the question. By what mechanism should I update `errorMessage` if it exists outside of the store sub-object visible to  `slidesReducer`? Do I simply create a reducer for the root of the object, and listen for `FETCH_SLIDES_ERROR` there too?

Comment: I think you can make every reducer has its own error message to show the user a different error according to the state of fetching or anything else

Comment: OK, thank you. I agree that sounds like a good solution. But, this example is contrived: how can I update a property outside of the sub-store. Do I simply listen to the same action in two different reducers?

Comment: I don't recommend you to do this cause they have the same action type name... in react hooks world i simply use context API and use reducer hook to make nice and clean state management or even I used MobX.

Comment: So the convention is to only listen to each action in a single location?